# How to implement sort & search on dynamic fields?

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

Currently my application use MSSQL for Sorting and Searching.

The data in the app is a list of Tasks,
Every Task can have multiple dynamic values (unknown number).

Example:

```
    Task1 – DynValue1, DynValue2, DynValue3
    Task2 – DynValue1, DynValue2
    Task3 – DynValue1, DynValue2, DynValue3, DynValue4, …
```

I want to be able to search tasks by DynValues and also to Sort by DynValue,
Example:

```
Sort by DynValue2 
Search for “ABC”, 
Return first 50 rows.
```

What will be the best way to implement Sort & Search in this case ?

The only way that I found that allows sorting is to build a field for every DynValue in Lucene for a limited fixed number of Dynamic values, but it’ll work only for the first X DynValues and I’m not sure how a large number of columns will effect performance in Lucene.

Comment: What do you mean by "Sort by DynValue"?  Which one should it sort on?

Comment: What is a DynValue? What does your SQL schema looks like?

Comment: There is a tasks table, and DynValues table (id, value), each task can have multiple DynValues.

Comment: How are the `Task`s related to the `DynValue`s?